# Beckhoff C# Library from windows machine without XAE/XAR

Tags: c#, plc, twincat

Is it possible to use Bechoff's C# library to connect to PLC from a windows machine without XAR/XAE installed ?
Similar to what you can do with C++ example.
I am keep getting

```
Exception thrown: 'TwinCAT.Ads.Server.LoopbackNotRegisteredException' in TwinCAT.Ads.Server.dll
```

when I try this despite adding route on PLC to my laptop's local IP address.

[image]

I am following this YT tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZChSdU2LMc

Answer (score 1):

from this [nuget source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Beckhoff.TwinCAT.Ads) it seems that you can:

> Install the 'Beckhoff.TwinCAT.Ads.AdsRouterConsole' package from Nuget.org

Disclaimer:

This will only work for

> TwinCAT Version >= 4024.10

Comment: well it still means I need to install "something" on that machine which is not always possible. It's not required with their C++ example so there's clearly something missing in C# libraries...

Comment: @ArkadiuszRycyk I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716863/how-to-create-a-twincat-ads-route-in-windows-without-the-twincat-system-applicat) tell me if it is helpful.